# How do I migrate data from Outlook 2007 to Thunderbird?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, migration, pst

I'm trying to migrate from Outlook 2007 to Thunderbird 7, and I'm stuck with moving my messages/folders.

What I'm supposed to do is: In Thunderbird, *Tools → Import*, and choose *Outlook (2007)*, but it isn't there. The only option is *Outlook Express*, which I never used.

My primary mail client is set to Outlook 2007. I'm on Windows XP, 64 Bit.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to an IMAP server?  The easiest way may be to copy your emails from Outlook to an IMAP server, then use thunderbird to access the same IMAP server.

Alternatively, if you have Outlook Express installed, you can import the emails into OE first then into thunderbird.

Comment: Having said that, it is strange that Outlook is not listed.  What version of TB is it, and is Outlook properly installed and working?

Comment: Outlook is working fine, TB is the latest vesrion (7?), downloaded today.
I dont have access to any imap server. I tried to export pst in Outlook 2007, but i can't import it in OE. What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: You should be able to instigate the import from OE directly from Outlook without first doing an export: File/Import/Messages/Microsoft Outlook

Comment: Ohh, something is really bad with my outlook. :/ When tried to follow Pauls direction, i got the following error message: MAPI is not installed on this computer or an error occured while initalize it.

Comment: Ah good, that explains why TB wasn't working either.  A reinstall of Outlook would be the way to go.

Comment: Well, no goal. Uninstalled, and reinstalled, mapi is still missing. Is this thing a service, or what?

Comment: Do you have any MAPI*.dll files in your c:\windows\system32 folder?

Comment: I have mapi32.dll and mapistub.dll. Same in syswow64 folder.
Thx for the help Paul, but now i have to sleep (02 here), maybee tomorrow i can find someting (today googled 4-5 hours before wrote here).